# Relationship problems

Tags: codefluent

I have a trial copy of the Codefluent for Entities and trying to model my first model before buying.

However looking in some early videos it seems that it's possible to have the information about the relation in the way i want to see it.

When doing this now and also looking in newer video it seems that the info of the relation is related to the property at the connected end. 
I have used and using llblgen orm tool and it's a bit confusing having it the "opposite". 
Is it possible to change this visual behaviour?
Thank's for any assitans and advice
//Greg

Comment: What do you mean by "the info of the relation is related to the property at the connected end"?

Comment: I've been using Codefluent Entities for a long time and I still don't fully understand how to read the model in terms of one-Many,Many-One, Many-Many etc. I think it would be good if CodeFluent Entities wrote a document specifically on how to read and understand the model. I also remember everything seemed backwards when I first started using it.

Comment: Thanks. Then it's a by design feature, i can live by that. Just a little confusing. I have just managed to generate servicestack files from a custom template.